# Выпадающее меню по клику

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="itemsMenu">
    <a href="#">
        <li>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <p>новинки</p>
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  
        </li>
    </a>

    <div class="dropMenu">
        <ul>
            <a href=""><li><p>Носки</p></li></a>
            <a href=""><li><p>Сандали</p></li></a>
            <a href=""><li><p>Ботинки</p></li></a>
            <a href=""><li><p>Носки</p></li></a>
            <a href=""><li><p>Сандали</p></li></a>
            <a href=""><li><p>Ботинки</p></li></a>
            <a href=""><li><p>Носки</p></li></a>
            <a href=""><li><p>Сандали</p></li></a>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, нужно чтобы по клику на `itemsMenu` выпадало меню `dropMenu` и чтобы при повторном клике оно исчезала, а так же чтобы при кликах на другие `itemsMenu` исчезло прошлое `dropMenu`, буду очень благодарен, если сможете помочь

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.itemsMenu>a').click(function() {
    $('.itemsMenu>a').removeClass('active');
    if ($(this).next('.dropMenu').css("display") == "none") {
      $('.dropMenu').hide('normal');
      $(this).next('.dropMenu').toggle('normal');
      $('.itemsMenu>a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
    } else $('.dropMenu').hide('normal');
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.dropMenu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
-2 голос против избранное
<div class="itemsMenu">
  <a href="#">
    <li>
      <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <p>новинки</p>
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </li>
  </a>

  <div class="dropMenu">
    <ul>
      <a href="">
        <li>
          <p>Носки</p>
        </li>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <li>
          <p>Сандали</p>
        </li>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <li>
          <p>Ботинки</p>
        </li>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <li>
          <p>Носки</p>
        </li>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <li>
          <p>Сандали</p>
        </li>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <li>
          <p>Ботинки</p>
        </li>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <li>
          <p>Носки</p>
        </li>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <li>
          <p>Сандали</p>
        </li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>

-2 голос против избранное
<div class="itemsMenu">
  <a href="#">
    <li>
      <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <p>новинки</p>
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </li>
  </a>

  <div class="dropMenu">
    <ul>
      <a href="">
        <li>
          <p>Носки</p>
        </li>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <li>
          <p>Сандали</p>
        </li>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <li>
          <p>Ботинки</p>
        </li>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <li>
          <p>Носки</p>
        </li>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <li>
          <p>Сандали</p>
        </li>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <li>
          <p>Ботинки</p>
        </li>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <li>
          <p>Носки</p>
        </li>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <li>
          <p>Сандали</p>
        </li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>

-2 голос против избранное
<div class="itemsMenu">
  <a href="#">
    <li>
      <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <p>новинки</p>
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </li>
  </a>

  <div class="dropMenu">
    <ul>
      <a href="">
        <li>
          <p>Носки</p>
        </li>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <li>
          <p>Сандали</p>
        </li>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <li>
          <p>Ботинки</p>
        </li>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <li>
          <p>Носки</p>
        </li>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <li>
          <p>Сандали</p>
        </li>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <li>
          <p>Ботинки</p>
        </li>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <li>
          <p>Носки</p>
        </li>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <li>
          <p>Сандали</p>
        </li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: спасибо,все работает

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.itemsMenu > a').on('click', function(e){
    //внутри нашего пункта меню находим "выпадашку"
    var $dropMenu = $(this).parent().find('.dropMenu');
    //если наш dropMenu видимый - скрываем, если скрыт - показываем
    if($dropMenu.is(':visible')){
        $dropMenu.hide();
    } else {
        //скрываем все видимые "выпадашки" на странице        
        $('.dropMenu:visible').hide(); 
        $dropMenu.show();
    }
});
```

Если хочется анимацию появления и скрытия пункта меню, то это можно сделать двумя способами:

- с помощью *JS* и *jQuery*, используя `$element.animate(...)` вместо `.show` и `.hide` в примере выше. Или, для простого эффекта плавного появления-исчезновения, можно использовать `.fadeIn()` и `.fadeOut()`.
- с помощью *CSS transition*. В этом случае нужно добавить в *css transition* свойства к анимируемому элементу (`.dropMenu` в нашем случае) и вместо `.show` и `.hide` присваивать или убирать класс, которым изменяются анимируемые параметры элемента (допустим, `left` и `opacity` для "выезжания" выпадашки с одновременным появлением).